# Listing of pre-determined batch variables

Tags: function, variables, batch-file

I was just wondering what all types of Variables in a batch are already set / Pre-determined when a batch is launched i know about these below:

```
%Time%
%Date%
%errorlevel%
%userprofile%
%username%
%appdata%
%systemroot%
%computername%
%tmp%
```

Is there any others im missing? because i would really like to know them all, or as
many as possible, since i know they can be a big help when helping out friends, or other
people with batches since not everyone has the same names in directories like %userprofile% a list of what others there are besides this list would be greatly appreciated, Thanks for anyone who helps in advance.

p.s. and for the new ones if any listed, a little example or sentence on what they do or achieve would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following link

[Wikipedia: Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: Thanks i'll select this as the answer when i can :D

Comment: lol, well that and its nice to actually get some help from people every once in a while.

Comment: You might also want to look at this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true
I'm not sure if it's out of date (it's for XP). And I thin running just `set` may show you them all.

Comment: Ok, ill Favorite the page, and look at it when i can, Appreciate the help.

Any help is good help, im running Win 7 so ill probably find out if its out of date with trial and error :3 thats how i get most things working.

Oh and thanks for the Set advice, it does reveal all of the variables that are set.. Much obliged :D